# uploading an app directory into firebase storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to set up my project in Firebase and can't seem to find an one shot way to upload my entire directory into a firebase storage bucket. Any thoughts? or is this a premium feature?

Comment: This is not an answer, but did you tried to use [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) and [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#copy)?, when you create a firebase project a GCP project is created too.
 
    `gsutil cp` command works in the same way as linux `cp` command you can copy a folder to your bucket by using `gsutil cp -r ./myfolder gs://mybucket`

Comment: Since I fear a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what are you trying to accomplish by uploading your project directory to Cloud Storage for Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

What you're calling "Firebase Storage" is actually the product [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) with Firebase client APIs and tools added on.  You can deal with the storage bucket created by Firebase in the same way that you treat any Cloud Storage bucket.  This means you can use the [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) command line program to [copy files](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) from your machine into that bucket.  This is not a premium feature.

Comment: thank you Doug! I guess the days of FTPing your way around are over :).

Comment: if anyone needs the command line for copying your files over to the firebase bucket here it is: `gsutil cp Desktop/kitten.png gs://my-awesome-bucket`